# Makefile change to select between files of different format

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I currently have files in .c and .cpp file format in my project. I wanted to automate the object file generation in Makefile to dynamically select the .c or .cpp file based on the availability of the file.

Currently,

```
obj/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(MKDEPEND) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $<
```

Sample solution

```
obj/%.o : %.cpp (OR) %.c
    $(CXX) $(MKDEPEND) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $<
```

Any solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make two different rules.  You don't want to use the same recipe for both anyway (you don't want to use a C++ compiler to compile C code).

```
obj/%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(MKDEPEND) -c -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $<

obj/%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(MKDEPEND) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $<
```

Make will try to match both rules and use whichever one matches, ignoring the others.